# A problem with compiling with the Texstudio editor

Tags: compiling, texstudio

After downloading the newest version of TexStudio (2.12.2) I've got the following problem. When I work with multiple tex-files in the editor and try to compile and build my current file (my settings for the root document: detect automatically), I don't always get the right file.

For some reason, in order to get the right file to be compiled, I need first to save this tex-file explicitly (so not the automatic saving by compiling the file), and then compile and build it.

Did I accidentally change some settings or is this some kind of bug?

Comment: Which operating system do you use?

Comment: And if you declate it as `root document`?

Comment: I use MacOS; if I set it as root document it works but this is annoying since I need to switch between tex-files